# QGIS extracting values from a shapefile

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression

I am looking to extract all features that have a field with values above 0 from a shapefile, then export the selected features. I can do an advanced expression such as:

`'Field' Not Like '0'`

which will leave me with the features I want. However, then, I have to go into the attribute table and highlight these values, then right click on the layer -> Save as -> Save selected Feature.

Is there a way to save the features all in one run?

Comment: "'`Field' Not Like '0'`" is a curious selection statement. Since the literal `'Field'` is never `like` the literal `'0'`,  the expression is akin to `1 = 1`. And without a wildcard in the `like` pattern, this would be much slower than the equivalent *not equals* (`<>`).

Answer (score 8):

Use the QGIS [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) algorithm with the following expression:

```
 "Field" > 0
```

Replace `Field` with your field name, set where to save the results and then run the algorithm.